# How can I tell regex to match literally the same string?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a string:

```
#Macro
#object
value=1
value=2
#EndMacroEnt
#object
value=5
value=6
#EndMacroEnt
#EndMacro
```

And now I want to parse out everything between #Macro and #EndMacro. 
Currently I am using this regex:

```
/(#Macro(.|[\r\n])+?#EndMacro)/g
```

The Problem is, that this regex stops at `#EndMacroEnt` too! How can I modify it, to use EXACT string `#EndMacro` and not `#EndMacroEnt`?

[Here is also online regex preview.](https://regex101.com/r/hT3rI9/1)

Comment: As an aside, to be more efficient, replace `(.|[\r\n])+?` with `[\s\S]+?` or `([\s\S]+?)` if you want to capture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add word boundaries at both start and end tags:

```
/(#Macro\b[\s\S]+?#EndMacro\b)/gi
```

PS: Also to match any character including newlines it is better to use:

```
[\s\S]
```

rather than:

```
(.|[\r\n])
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add `\b` to match at the word boundary. This will include `#Macro` and `#EndMacro` into Group 1:

`(#Macro\b(.|[\r\n])+?)#EndMacro\b)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bZ6iX9/3)

As for matching newlines, you can use the trick shown by @anubhava, or just any of `[\w\W]*?`, `[\d\D]*?`, etc.

So, the code could be

```js
var re = /(#Macro\b[\d\D]+?#EndMacro\b)/g; 
var str = '#Macro\r\n#object\r\nvalue=1\r\nvalue=2\r\n#EndMacroEnt\r\n#object\r\nvalue=5\r\nvalue=6\r\n#EndMacroEnt\r\n#EndMacro';
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += "<br>" + m[1].trim().replace(/\r\n/g,"<br>");
}
```

```html
<div id="res" />
```